# Using apache camel csv processor with pollEnrich pattern?

Tags: apache-camel

Apache Camel 2.12.1

Is it possible to use the Camel CSV component with a pollEnrich? Every example I see is like:

```
from("file:somefile.csv").marshal...
```

Whereas I'm using the pollEnrich, like:

```
pollEnrich("file:somefile.csv", new CSVAggregator())
```

So within CSVAggregator I have no csv...I just have a file, which I have to do csv processing myself. So is there a way of hooking up the marshalling to the enrich bit somehow...?

**EDIT**

To make this more general... eg:

```
from("direct:start")
.to("http:www.blah")
.enrich("file:someFile.csv", new CSVAggregationStrategy) <--how can I call marshal() on this?
```

...

```
public class CSVAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) { 
/*  Here I have:
oldExchange = results of http blah endpoint
newExchange = the someFile.csv GenericFile object */
```

}

Is there any way I can avoid this and use marshal().csv sort of call on the route itself?

Thanks,

Mr Tea

Answer (score 2):

You can use any endpoint in enrich. That includes direct endpoints pointing to other routes. Your example...

Replace this:

```
from("direct:start")
  .to("http:www.blah")
  .enrich("file:someFile.csv", new CSVAggregationStrategy)
```

With this:

```
from("direct:start")
  .to("http:www.blah")
  .enrich("direct:readSomeFile", new CSVAggregationStrategy);

from("direct:readSomeFile")
  .to("file:someFile.csv")
  .unmarshal(myDataFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and managed to solve it with the following code (note, I'm using the scala dsl). My use case was slightly different, I wanted to load a CSV file and enrich it with data from an additional static CSV file.

```
from("direct:start") pollEnrich("file:c:/data/inbox?fileName=vipleaderboard.inclusions.csv&noop=true") unmarshal(csv)
from("file:c:/data/inbox?fileName=vipleaderboard.${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv") unmarshal(csv) enrich("direct:start", (current:Exchange, myStatic:Exchange) => {
    // both exchange in bodies will contain lists instead of the file handles
})
```

Here the second route is the one which looks for a file in a specific directory. It unmarshals the CSV data from any matching file it finds and enriches it with the direct route defined in the preceding line. That route is `pollEnriching` with my static file and as I don't define an aggregation strategy it just replaces the contents of the body with the static file data. I can then unmarshal that from CSV and return the data.

The aggregation function in the second route then has access to both files' CSV data as `List<List<String>>` instead of just a file.