# Camel - Enrich CSV from FTP with CSV from local disk using Camel Bindy

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

The goal is to produce a report every hour by comparing two CSV files with 
use of Camel 3.0.0. One is located on a FTP server, the other on disk. How to use poll enrich pattern in combination with unmarshalling the CSV on disk with Bindy Dataformat?

Example code (for simplicity the FTP endpoint is replaced by a file endpoint):

```java
@Component
public class EnricherRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("file://data?fileName=part_1.csv&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0+0/1+*+*+?")
            .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Record.class)
            .pollEnrich("file://data?fileName=part_2.csv", new ReportAggregationStrategy())
            .marshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Record.class)
            .to("file://reports?fileName=report_${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv");

    }
}
```

The problem in this example is that in the `ReportAggregationStrategy` the `resource` (coming from `data/part_2.csv`, see below) is not unmarshalled. How to unmarshal `data/part_2.csv` as well?

```java
public class ReportAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        final List<Record> originalRecords = original.getIn().getBody(List.class);
        final List<Record> resourceRecords = resource.getIn().getBody(List.class); // Results in errors!

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap enrichment with [direct endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html) and do unmarshaling there.

```
from("file://data?fileName=part_1.csv&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0+0/1+*+*+?")
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Record.class)
    .enrich("direct:enrich_record", new ReportAggregationStrategy())
    .marshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Record.class)
    .to("file://reports?fileName=report_${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv");

from("direct:enrich_record")
    .pollEnrich("file://data?fileName=part_2.csv")
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, Record.class);
```

Comment: I had tried the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696860) but without luck. Would never thought of using `enrich` and `pollEnrich` in this combination. Nice and well done!